intellij cannot resolve dependencies from gradle configuration
I have a gradle project with a custom configuration for my contract tests that gets created from a source set. The contract tests live under src/test/java/com/mycompany/myapp/contracttest
(snippet source: https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.2/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests)
sourceSets {
  contractTest { 
    compileClassPath += sourceSets.main.output
    runtimeClassPath += sourceSets.main.output
    java {
      srcDir "src/test/java"
      include "**/contracttest/*"
    }
  }
  test {
    java {
      exclude "**/contracttest/*"
    }
  }
}
configurations {
  contractTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
  contractTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}

dependencies {
  contractTestImplementation "group:artifact:version"
}

Then, my contract tests can import classes from group:artifact:version module.
This works when I run contract tests. My problem is that Intellij marks classes from group:artifact:version with Cannot resolve symbol
I tried adding it somehow to idea like so
idea {
  module {
    scopes.COMPILE.plus += [configurations.contractTestCompileClasspath]
  }
}

however it didn't help.
P.S. Inspecting my project in Project Structure, I see some interesting things. First, "group:artifact:version" does show up under libraries. Second, in modules, there seems to be a contractTest module which expects to have src/contractTest content root.

This YouTrack Issue might be related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-234382/Gradle-integration-tests-are-not-marked-as-test-sources-resources

@romanv-jb thanks, but that issue is about sources, however my issue is about libraries

Would it be possible to share the Project or a sample reproducer Project with the structure, so we can take a closer look at the issue?

OK, I have an answer. There may be a better answer, but this is what I got so far.
Gradle source sets are mapped to intellij modules. Gradle has flexibility with sourceSets that IntelliJ doesn't have with modules, specifically, while Gradle allows selecting one package to be one source set, and another to be a different source set, IntelliJ demands that ever module has a unique content root.
